# Coldfusion cfset XML variable with cfloop

Tags: xml, coldfusion, cfml

I wanted to see if you would be able to help me some syntax.... I have been trying to build an XML dataset which includes user data. However when I cfset the loop of the user data, the XML includes the cfloop code.

Here is the code:

```
<cfset map_vars = '<MAP>" +  "<location>#get_alert.address#</location>" +
                    <cfloop query="get_users">
                    "<user_info>" + 
                    "<user_name>#get_users.sub_firstname# #get_users.sub_lastname#</user_name>" + 
                    "<user_lat>#get_users.CAD_Call_lat#</user_lat>" + 
                    "<user_lon>#get_users.CAD_Call_lon#</user_lon>" + 
                    "<user_img>https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.wbur.org/wordpress/1/files/2015/03/AP736858445562.jpg</user_img>" +
                    "</user_info>" + 
                    </cfloop>
                    "</MAP>'>
```

And what the output is:

```
        <MAP>" +  "<location>12345 LINCOLN HILL RD Martinsville</location>" +
                    <cfloop query="get_users">
                    "<user_info>" + 
                    "<user_name>Bill Jones</user_name>" + 
                    "<user_lat>41.1421443662058</user_lat>" + 
                    "<user_lon>-81.5781682078555</user_lon>" + 
                    "<user_img>https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.wbur.org/wordpress/1/files/2015/03/AP736858445562.jpg</user_img>" +
                    "</user_info>" + 
                    </cfloop>
                    "</MAP>
```

So you can see it is including the cfloop tags.

Any ideas where be so appreciate!!!

Answer (score 4):

The string starts by the single quote and has to be ended with a single quote. However, I would use a `cfsavecontent` tag. That makes everything much more readable

```
<cfsavecontent variable="map_vars"><cfoutput>
    <MAP><location>#get_alert.address#</location>
        <cfloop query="get_users">
            <user_info> 
                <user_name>#get_users.sub_firstname# #get_users.sub_lastname#</user_name> 
                <user_lat>#get_users.CAD_Call_lat#</user_lat> 
                <user_lon>#get_users.CAD_Call_lon#</user_lon> 
                <user_img>https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.wbur.org/wordpress/1/files/2015/03/AP736858445562.jpg</user_img>
            </user_info> 
        </cfloop>
    </MAP>
</cfoutput></cfsavecontent>
```

There's a `cfxml` tag that helps with validation: https://cfdocs.org/cfxml

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Bernhard's answer, I would add in `encodeForXML()` to make sure strings are properly escaped.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="map_vars"><cfoutput>
    <MAP><location>#EncodeForXML(get_alert.address)#</location>
        <cfloop query="get_users">
            <user_info> 
                <user_name>#EncodeForXML(get_users.sub_firstname)# #EncodeForXML(get_users.sub_lastname)#</user_name> 
                <user_lat>#EncodeForXML(get_users.CAD_Call_lat)#</user_lat> 
                <user_lon>#EncodeForXML(get_users.CAD_Call_lon)#</user_lon> 
                <user_img>https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.wbur.org/wordpress/1/files/2015/03/AP736858445562.jpg</user_img>
            </user_info> 
        </cfloop>
    </MAP>
</cfoutput></cfsavecontent>
```

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback. I appreciate it so much. I am trying to add it into the code and everything seems to look correct, but I am getting the following error that location is undefined. I have checked the tags to make sure they are the same but just still get the error. as you can see I also added in all the quotes and removed spaces....

Comment: <cfsavecontent variable="map_vars">
<cfoutput>'<MAP>" +  "<location>#EncodeForXML(get_alert.address)#</location>" + <cfloop query="get_users">"<user_info>" + "<user_name>#EncodeForXML(get_users.sub_firstname)# #EncodeForXML(get_users.sub_lastname)#</user_name>" + "<user_lat>#EncodeForXML(get_users.CAD_Call_lat)#</user_lat>" + "<user_lon>#EncodeForXML(get_users.CAD_Call_lon)#</user_lon>" + "<user_img>https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.wbur.org/wordpress/1/files/2015/03/AP736858445562.jpg</user_img>" + "</user_info>" + </cfloop>"</MAP>'</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

Comment: var parser = new DOMParser();
                var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml_data, "text/xml");
                var address = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(location)[0].textContent;
                var users = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("user_info");
                var user_list = [];

Comment: Here is the error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(location)[0].textContent')

Comment: You should write up a new question on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually after playing around with a few things.... got it to work simply by removing the single quotes before and after the map tags.

Thank you both James & Bernhard for the feedback. Works perfectly. You guys are the KINGS!!!!

Thanks!

Comment: You should come back and mark Bernhard's answer as correct.